# Sharing  session (JSP) in 2 different  project

Tags: eclipse, jsp, session

is there anyway of sharing the Session data across two different JSP (i mean two dynamic web project)
projects

in the 1st project i test like that

```
  <%if(session.getAttribute("UserName") != null ){%>
  .
  .
   do something
     .
    <% } %>
```

it's ok

but when i do that in the 2nd project i got this exception

```
Etat HTTP 404 - /myEbookSearchClient/myEBook/WebContent/JSP/session/index.jsp

  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   type Rapport d''état

    message /myEbookSearchClient/myEBook/WebContent/JSP/session/index.jsp

   description La ressource demandée (/myEbookSearchClient/myEBook/WebContent/JSP/session/index.jsp)        n'est pas disponible.


   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Apache Tomcat/7.0.5
```

Basically, I'm jumping from a page in one to a page in another

any idea how to Shar the session of the 1st project with the 2 project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant. Attempting to share sessions is discouraged for a variety of reasons primarily related to security.

Servlet contexxt methods that retreieve a session by id or return an enumeration of all now all do nothing for precisely this reason.

You will need to share data in some other manner such as a cache or via a database.

Comment: but the session is on the server , i want to understand how can i get from the server in outher project